# How to get information on GitLab repositories' contributors with GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, gitlab, repository

I would like to pull information with GraphQL on GitLab's projects/repositories regarding **contributors**.

Not sure how to get to repository stats inside project and whether such information even exists?

I know how to pull basic info on name, creation date, stars, forks, languages and issues from GitLab's projects:

```
{
  group(fullPath: "MyGroup") {
    projects(first: 100) {
      count
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          createdAt
          starCount
          forksCount
          lastActivityAt
          languages {
            name
          }
          issueStatusCounts {
            all
            closed
            opened
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to do it for GitHub, although when it comes to contributors, you need to make a workaround with reaching to commits (that makes sense) - I found solution for GH here:
https://maravindblog.wordpress.com/2021/08/12/how-to-get-contributors-using-github-graphql/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.